# Python AWS Lambda Web scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, aws-lambda

I need to scrape a URL to send content to my Lambda function. I am trying to achieve it by packaging BeautifulSoup with my Lambda function, but I am getting import errors like: cannot import name 'CharsetMetaAttributeValue' etc. I am not sure if bs4 should be used in AWS environment or not.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Have you checked Lambda's docs?

Comment: @hjpotter92, checked Lambda docs, but seems aws doesn't provide any inbuilt thing for creating scraper.

Comment: What I meant was https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Answer (score 2):

I am able to use compiled lxml package with Lambda function for web scraper. Compiled package is available at github this link: https://github.com/JFox/aws-lambda-lxml/tree/master/3.6.4